# SASS Parent selector from another selector with @at-root

Tags: css, sass

I have:

```
.parent {
   &.change {
     .logo {
       width:100px;
     }
   }
}


.logo {
  &.logo--one {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
  }
  &.logo--two {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
  }  
  &.logo--tree {
    border:1px solid #fff;
  }  
}
```

I would like from inside of each logo name to be able to change a selector like

```
.parent.change .logo.logo--one {}
```

without having to repeat the logos names. I have a lot of logo names. Something like the code below that **doesn't** work as desired

```
.logo {
  &.logo--one {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    @at-root .what__should__be__here {
      width:100px;
    }
  }
  &.logo--two {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    @at-root .what__should__be__here {
      width:100px;
    }
  }  
  &.logo--tree {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    @at-root .what__should__be__here {
      width:100px;
    }
  }  
}
```

You can play with it here I think: http://sassmeister.com/gist/21b2886c6a572446684c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `&` (which is not really intuitive, but works). I found the solution here: http://davidwalsh.name/future-sass

This is the result: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9ebc671927a4dacd6405

```
.parent {
   &.change {
     .logo {
       width:100px;
     }
   }
}


.logo {
  &.logo--one {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    @at-root .parent.change & {
      width:100px;
    }
  }
  &.logo--two {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    @at-root .parent.change & {
      width:120px;
    }
  }  
  &.logo--tree {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    @at-root .parent.change & {
      width:130px;
    }
  }  
}
```

This is the best use case for `@at-root` I have found so far.